# How to deserialize Jackson Json NULL String to Date with JsonFormat

Tags: json, string, date, null, jackson

I have looked a lot but still couldn't get the answer so far, any help is really appreciated!

I have a simple `String` to `Date` field mapping and try to read a JSON string to Java object.

```
@JsonInclude(value=Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy", timezone="PST")
protected Date eolAnnounceDate;
```

However I am getting the following exception if the JSON string value is empty.
Can you someone tell me how to get around this? I have tried a few options but they are all for serialization.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();   
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL); 
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
```

Exception :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to parse Date value 'NULL' (format: "dd-MMM-yyyy"): Unparseable date: "NULL"
>       com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DateDeserializers$DateBasedDeserializer._parseDate(DateDeserializers.java:180)
>       com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DateDeserializers$DateDeserializer.deserialize(DateDeserializers.java:279)
>       com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DateDeserializers$DateDeserializer.deserialize(DateDeserializers.java:260)
>       com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:464)
>       com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:98)
>       com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:295)
>       com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:121)
>       com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:230)
>       com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:207)
>       com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:23)
>       com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:464)
>       com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:98)
>       com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:295)
>       com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:121)
>       com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
>       com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2034)
>       com.cisco.cre.dao.impl.ElasticsearchDAOImpl.getListByIdsFilter(ElasticsearchDAOImpl.java:94)

Thanks
- Atul

Answer (score 21):

Your problem is not that a null value is passed in the JSON. The problem is that the JSON contains a string that has the value `"NULL"`.

So, in order to fix this there are a number of available approaches. I think that the following two will work for this case.

**Alternative 1: Fix the JSON**

The first alternative is to fix the JSON so that it does not contain the the string value `"NULL"` and instead contain the value `null` (not quoted) or simply skip it.

Imagine the following POJO:

```
public class DatePojo {
    @JsonInclude(value= JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy", timezone="PST")
    @JsonProperty("date")
    private Date date;
}
```

The following test shows that valid dates, empty values and `null` values work:

```
@Test
public void testJson() throws IOException {
    String jsonWithValidDate = "{\"date\":\"12-Jun-1982\"}";
    String jsonWithNoDate = "{}";
    String jsonWithNullDate = "{\"date\":null}";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final DatePojo pojoWithValidDate = mapper.readValue(jsonWithValidDate, DatePojo.class);
    final DatePojo pojoWithNoDate = mapper.readValue(jsonWithNoDate, DatePojo.class);
    final DatePojo pojoWithNullDate = mapper.readValue(jsonWithNullDate, DatePojo.class);

    Assert.assertNotNull(pojoWithValidDate.date);
    Assert.assertNull(pojoWithNoDate.date);
    Assert.assertNull(pojoWithNullDate.date);
}
```

However, if you pass along the value `"NULL"` the test fails since `"NULL"` can not be parsed as a date:

```
@Test(expected = JsonMappingException.class)
public void testInvalidJson() throws IOException {
    String jsonWithNullString = "{\"date\":\"NULL\"}";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.readValue(jsonWithNullString, DatePojo.class); // Throws the exception
    Assert.fail();
}
```

**Alternative 2: provide your own converter that handles `"NULL"`**

If it is not possible to fix the JSON (as described in alternative 1) you can provide your own converter.

Setup your pojo like this instead:

```
public class DatePojo {
    @JsonProperty("date")
    @JsonDeserialize(converter = MyDateConverter.class)
    private Date date;
}
```

And provide a converter along the lines of:

```
public class MyDateConverter extends StdConverter<String, Date> {
    @Override
    public Date convert(final String value) {
        if (value == null || value.equals("NULL")) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").parse(value);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to parse date", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you should be all set. The following test passes:

```
@Test
public void testJson() throws IOException {
    String jsonWithValidDate = "{\"date\":\"12-Jun-1982\"}";
    String jsonWithNoDate = "{}";
    String jsonWithNullDate = "{\"date\":null}";
    String jsonWithNullString = "{\"date\":\"NULL\"}"; // "NULL"

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final DatePojo pojoWithValidDate = mapper.readValue(jsonWithValidDate, DatePojo.class);
    final DatePojo pojoWithNoDate = mapper.readValue(jsonWithNoDate, DatePojo.class);
    final DatePojo pojoWithNullDate = mapper.readValue(jsonWithNullDate, DatePojo.class);
    final DatePojo pojoWithNullStr = mapper.readValue(jsonWithNullString, DatePojo.class); // Works

    Assert.assertNotNull(pojoWithValidDate.date);
    Assert.assertNull(pojoWithNoDate.date);
    Assert.assertNull(pojoWithNullDate.date);
    Assert.assertNull(pojoWithNullStr.date); // Works
}
```

IMO, the best approach is to use alternative 1 where you simply change the JSON.

Comment: Thanks a lot wassgren ! You really found the problem, actually the Json was coming from Elasticsearch and it very large so I didn't notice the "NULL" date :-)

Comment: @apald, If this helped to solve your problem it would be nice if you would "accept" the answer (the green tick) so that the question is marked as solved properly!

Comment: @wassgren, great and thorough answer, thank you!