# How to ignore a NULL value during Deserialization in lamda stream?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson2

I have getter method

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public Date getVerifiedFrom() {
    if(invoices == null || invoices.isEmpty()) {
       return null;
    }
    return invoices.stream().filter(i->i.getVerifiedDate() != null).map(Invoice::getVerifiedDate).min(Date::compareTo).get();
}
```

I have tried few link but those are not helped,

http://www.java2novice.com/java-json/jackson/ignore-json-null-elements/

[How to deserialize Jackson Json NULL String to Date with JsonFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123887/how-to-deserialize-jackson-json-null-string-to-date-with-jsonformat)

http://www.davismol.net/2016/01/08/jackson-how-to-exclude-null-value-properties-from-json-serialization/

[How to tell Jackson to ignore a field during serialization if its value is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null)

Error:

```
Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: No value present; 
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No value present (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.enkindle.service.resource.TradeDebtResource["verifiedFrom"])
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the annotation on the field instead of the getter method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell Jackson to ignore a field during serialization if its value is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you’re getting is due to the stream being empty, which causes `min` to return an empty optional which throws an exception when you call `get`.
The reason you don’t get the original NPE is that Jackson probably extracts just the message.

You should replace `get()` with `orElse(null)`.
There’s also a Jackson module that handles `Optional`.